# google-cloud pubsub leaves messages in queue after sending ack

Tags: google-api, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have this subscriber code:

```
    try {

        //subscriber
        syncSubscriber.createSubscriber(SdkServiceConfig.s.SUBSCRIPTION_NAME_PARTNER_REQUEST);

        final List<ReceivedMessage> messages = syncSubscriber.fetch(10, true);//get all current messages.
        List<String> ackIds = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ReceivedMessage message : messages) {
            requestToCofmanSender.receiveMessage(message.getMessage());
            ackIds.add(message.getAckId());
        }

        //preferred bulk ack, due to network performance
        syncSubscriber.sendAck(ackIds);


        requestToCofmanSender.getWazePublisher().shutdown();
    }
```

and

```
public void sendAck(Collection<String> ackIdList) {
    if (ackIdList != null && ackIdList.size() != 0) {
        String subscriptionName = SubscriptionName.format(this.getProjectId(), this.subscriptionId);
        AcknowledgeRequest acknowledgeRequest = AcknowledgeRequest.newBuilder().setSubscription(subscriptionName).addAllAckIds(ackIdList).build();
        this.subscriber.acknowledgeCallable().call(acknowledgeRequest);
    }
}
```

I poll the `pubsub` queue in loop

and even though the code sends `ack` i still get the same messages.

how should i ack otherwise?

Comment: which client library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that i had a break point between receiving the message and sending ack. My pubsub was configured to 10 seconds timeout.